# Outlook 2016 Search no results 16.16.8

Tags: ms-office, spotlight, search

We've been having a issue at our work where a handful of users have a problem with the search in Outlook 2016 for Mac. We have tried re-indexing their Spotlight. Doesn't resolve the problem. We have tried to manually reindex Spotlight via Terminal We have tried We have tried using Microsoft's Outlook re-indexing tool (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4483875/outlook-for-mac-support-utilities). Nothing works.
All the users that had this problem have changed to a new Mac. It is a fresh install and nothing has migrated from their old computer. Their search worked on the old Mac but no longer on the new Mac. Their search in webmail works perfectly.
We have transfered many computers but not all users have this search problem.
Has anyone else seen this issue? Is it the recent Microsoft Office update that has affected the search/spotlight?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with Outlook and Mojave talking to Spotlight (maybe specifically after an upgrade?), I've also found that this is an issue with Fusion Drives as well as it slows down Spotlight indexing. Microsoft is aware of the issue and is looking to investigate.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-doesn-t-work-in-outlook-for-mac-after-macos-upgrade-b73de6f1-aeb9-4720-bbbe-de65ab50012e

I've tried all of their steps in your link previously, currently, I'm using Onyx to fun the full maintenance scripts (Launch Services, and Spotlight Index). It's worked for me, for now...